# Do not use 404 pages on your website?

Tags: performance, http-status-code-404

I was reading this guide of best practices by Yahoo:
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#no404

One rule that caught my eye is this.

> HTTP requests are expensive so making an HTTP request and getting a
>   useless response (i.e. 404 Not Found) is totally unnecessary and will
>   slow down the user experience without any benefit.
>
> Some sites have helpful 404s "Did you mean X?", which is great for the
>   user experience but also wastes server resources (like database, etc).
>   Particularly bad is when the link to an external JavaScript is wrong
>   and the result is a 404. First, this download will block parallel
>   downloads. Next the browser may try to parse the 404 response body as
>   if it were JavaScript code, trying to find something usable in it.

Is this really best practice?? If a user enters the wrong url on my website, what is this guide recommending? That I just leave the user with the default server error page? If the user enters the wrong url, how can the server return anything other than a 404? I simply don't understand this advice and wonder if anyone can explain the reasoning, thank you.

Comment: Ain't this more appropriate at [sf] or [webmasters.se]?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about stuff that's really better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The essence of the quote is that you should have different 404 documents for different media types: resources, that are not intended to be directly requested, should not result in a detailed error document but rather simply be empty. The status code alone will tell the browser that the resource could not be found.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is that you serve different 404 documents in different situations.

For resources, that are not intended to be directly requested by a user but rather embedded into other documents (i.e., images, stylesheets, script files, etc.), should not result in a detailed error document but rather simply be empty, i.e., no body. With no body present, the browser won’t try to parse it.

But for resources, that are intended to be directly requested, a detailed 404 document with helpful information and guidance is better.

You could also take the presence of a *Referer* header field instead of the author’s intention as indicator whether a 404 document is useful or not.